# epylint output to variable

Tags: python, pylint

I need to execute analog of CLI `pylint ./**/*.py --disable=R0801 --max-line-length=200` from Python script, so I use epylint:

```
from pylint.epylint import lint
PYLINT_OUTPUT = lint('./', ['--exit-zero', '--disable=R0801', '--max-line-length=200'])
print(f'PYLINT_OUTPUT: {PYLINT_OUTPUT}')
```

For some reason `PYLINT_OUTPUT` is type of int and 0 as value:
[image]

How can I put epylint output to the variable?

I tried lint.py_ru :

```
from pylint import epylint as lint
(pylint_stdout, pylint_stderr) = lint.py_run('./', return_std=True)
print(f'pylint_stdout: {pylint_stdout.read()}')
```

..it works as expected but I didn't find a way how to put `'--exit-zero', '--disable=R0801', '--max-line-length=200'` parameters